# A head, a heart and a tail

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> A head, a heart and a tail
>   You ought to find me, so don't fail
>
> After my tail, send my head
>   From some bullets, I fled?
>   To make things new, now use me
>   And so to do, then affix me
>
> Take my heart and duplicate
>   Before my head, place it straight
>   Congrats, I was not very tall
>   But now, I'm nothing at all
>
> Great, now my tail is my head. Horror!
>   Fortunately, you let the rest in order
>   It is quite a long time, you see
>   I'll understand if you don't wait for me.

Who am I?

Comment: You are a three-letter word.

Comment: @randal'thor That is a start!

Comment: 'Fortunately you let the rest in order' should let be left?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil [Let is valid as well](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/let_1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you:

> 'one'

After my tail, send my head
From some bullets, I fled?
To make things new, now use me
And so to do, then affix me

> one -> Neo
>  [Neo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neo-) is a prefix meaning new or recent.

Take my heart and duplicate
Before my head, place it straight
Congrats, I was not very tall
But now, I'm nothing at all

> one -> none

Great, now my tail is my head. Horror!
Fortunately, you let the rest in order
It is quite a long time, you see

> one -> eon
>  An [eon](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/eon) is an extremely long period of time.

Comment: Hey, this is it! Explain the lines 5/6 and you're good to have the tick :-)

Comment: Hmm, I honestly can't get 5/6 right now.  I'll keep at it.

Comment: For 5/6: [it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neo-) is a prefix to denote something new.

Comment: Yes, this is what @Ankoganit says!

Comment: Ah, clever!  I was still thinking of 'one' instead of 'neo' for those lines.  Thanks @Ankoganit!